# How to request to two servers then return response with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I am creating a website which sends a request to another server then parse it and returns response. I use `requests` library in python to send request.
My code for sending request is here:

```
external_server_url = 'https://external_server.com/'
response = self.requests_session.get(external_server_url,
                                     headers={'user-agent': self._get_device_user_agent(),
                                              'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
                                              'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
                                              'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'})
return response.text
```

The architecture is like this:

[image]

But `requests` library is so slow. I have compared `nginx` redirect with `requests` and `nginx` redirect was so faster. The `nginx` code for redirecting is here:

```
server {
    listen 8888 ssl;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://external_server.com/ redirect;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I want to use new architecture which `nginx` sends a request to the external server and give it to the Django server. The new architecture is like this:

[image]

How can I create this architecture with `nginx` server?

Answer (score 0):

Culprit here is not *"requests"* library but remote server which does not close connection. Also there is a possibility that response contains some headers which are not compliant to standard and *"requests"* library does not process them properly and does not close connection from its side.

You can either downgrade http protocol from "1.1" to "1.0" (**to disable http keep-alive feature**) or you can add header into your request **"Connection: close"**, thus asking remote server to close connection after servicing request(effectively disabling keep-alive feature).

```
external_server_url = 'https://external_server.com/'
response = self.requests_session.get(
  external_server_url,
  headers={
    'Connection': 'close',
    'user-agent': self._get_device_user_agent(),
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'
  }
)
return response.text
```

Comment: My problem is requesting to the external server is slow and I want to make it faster. If I close the connection then it will become slower. Is it right?

Comment: you did not get it. The problem is that either remote server or library does not close connection at once. Idea is not for you to close connection but for the remote server. When you specify "Connection: close", it is hint for the remote server to close connection as soon as it sends you the last byte. Just check it

Comment: I have tested `connection: close` header but it did not help performance.

Comment: @hamid, could you please share URL with us? - you can also send it to me via skype(see my profile)